# Separating array inside JSONarray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have JSONArray in the form below and need to get each individual number out of it.

```
{
  "layout": [
    [
      "12",
      "21",
      "31"
    ],
    [
      "empty",
      "22",
      "32"
    ],
    [
      "13",
      "23",
      "33"
    ]
  ]
}
```

for example in first array `[12, 21, 31]` element inside `layout` array I need to get 12, 21, 31 individually

Currently I'm using this code

```
private void doImageLogic(String ParsedString, String metadata) { // sorts through images json and calls imageDownloader to get the bitmaps - e.g. retrieve apple.jpg
    Log.d("STRING_CHECK", "testing");

    try {
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ParsedString);
        JSONArray pictureFiles = j.getJSONArray("layout");
        for (int i = 0; i < pictureFiles.length(); i++ ){

            mJpegNames.add("http://www.simongrey.net/08027/slidingPuzzleAcw/images/"+ metadata+"/"+ pictureFiles.getJSONArray(i));
        }
        ImageDownload imageDownloader = new ImageDownload(mPuzzleItem, mContext);
        imageDownloader.execute(mJpegNames);
        Log.d("Test", "test");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

but this returns the 3 arrays within the JSONarray, I can't figure out how to access the nested Arrays.

Comment: `pictureFiles.get(index)`

Comment: Proper layout for json, plus added more description to explain what is the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ParsedString);
    JSONArray pictureFiles = j.getJSONArray("layout");

    for (int i = 0; i < pictureFiles.length(); i++ ){  
     JSONArray ja = pictureFiles.getJSONArray(i);
        for(int j=0;j<ja.length();j++){
          mJpegNames.add("http://www.simongrey.net/08027/slidingPuzzleAcw/images/"+ metadata+"/"+ ja.getString(j));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest a `for` loop that iterates through the inner arrays. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pictureFiles.length(); i++ ) {
    for (int k = 0; k < pictureFiles.getJSONArray(i).length(); k++) {  
        mJpegNames.add("http://www.simongrey.net/08027/" + 
                       "slidingPuzzleAcw/images/metadata/" + 
                       pictureFiles.getJSONArray(i).getString(k));
    }
}
```